# Name for context and representation in context of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I deal with tasks around manipulating position vectors, defined only by the head point. I was wondering about two related things:

What's the conventional name used for the context/reference space/base, position or matrix that define what's the Origin, Direction and Scale of the vectors referent to it?
I many times have to move vectors from the space of one object, to world space, than to another object space, do something and then backtrack the context (?) changing steps.
Image below there are two black vectors pointing to the same location but P is referent to the World and P' is referent to that 2x2 Matrix. So I can say P' is in the context? reference space?, base? of that 2x2 Matrix?
Some of my time is used in putting positions from one context(?) to another context(?), either just a Position B-A or a Matrix B*A⁻¹. So I would like to know the name of this operation.
[image: img]

Also, are there terms to describe when you represent a vector in context (red vectors in the next picture) and when you represent them like what the actual data you're manipulating looks like, sitting at the origin, (red vectors)?
[image: img]

Here B was put in context of A, rotated and the put back in it's original context.

Thanks for any enlightenment.
Cheers

Comment: If I understand your question in a proper way, the "context" looks to be what is called in Mathematics an **affine basis** $(O,\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2})$, constituted of a triple: an origin and two vectors.